# Закругленная форма изображения с использованием clip-path

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, css-shapes

Я хочу иметь css clip-path, как на изображении ниже

Кто-нибудь может мне помочь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(53% 0%, 100% 1%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 55% 100%, 42% 65%, 0% 52%, 44% 36%);
  border-radius:0 100% 100% 0
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Rounded image shape using clip-path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65108103/7394871) от участника  [@Suresh R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489768/suresh-r).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65108103/7394871

Comment: Выглядит как 3 дуги.

Comment: @Qwertiy ты прав, три дуги обрезают

Answer (score 6):

Если размеры картинки в пикселях фиксированы, можно использовать `clip-path: path()`, благо [поддерживается всеми современными браузерами](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_clip-path_path) (Opera, думаю, подтянется совсем скоро, когда обновит свою версию Blink).

Беда только в том, что [clip-path: path() совершенно не адаптивный](https://css-tricks.com/unfortunately-clip-path-path-is-still-a-no-go/) и задаёт координаты только в пикселях, так что придётся или фиксировать размер картинки в пикселях, или страдать, или ждать появления [адаптивного shape()](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/pull/5711) (то есть тоже страдать).

(Фигуру я нарисовал в Inkscape, потом просто скопировал получившийся path из SVG-кода.)

```css
img {
  clip-path: path("M 200 0 A 200 200 0 0 1 0 200 A 200 200 0 0 1 200 400 A 200 200 0 0 0 400 200 A 200 200 0 0 0 200 0 Z");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800" width="400" height="400" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Маска легко может это сделать. Было бы сложно получить кривую с clip-path

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle at top    left,transparent 45%,#fff 45.5%) top,
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,transparent 45%,#fff 45.5%) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:100% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800">
```

Другой синтаксис:

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(51% 51% at 0 0   ,transparent 99%,#fff),
    radial-gradient(51% 51% at 0 100%,transparent 99%,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-in;
  mask-composite:intersect;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65108435/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Ну вот, а потом Firefox вынужден добавлять поддержку `-webkit` префиксов...

Comment: @Sevastopol' можно оформить комментарий в качестве ответа

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант с 4 секторами

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="420" height="420" viewBox="0 0 420 420" version="1.1">
 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
   <g id="G1" transform="translate(10 -5)" fill="gold" stroke-width="3" stroke="orangered">
  <path d="M299.3 119.6A99.6 100.4 90 0 1 198.8 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 1 299.3 318.7 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 399.7 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 299.3 119.6ZM299.3 318.7" />
  <path d="m299.3 318.7a99.6 100.4 1 0 1-97.9-102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 1-101.2 98.8 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 97.9 102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 101.2-98.8z" />
  <path d="M98.9 316.6A100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 201.4 219.2 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 103 117.5 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 0.5 215 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 98.9 316.6Z" />
  <path d="M101.4 119.4A99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 200.8 220 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 300.6 119.7 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 201.1 19.1 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 101.4 119.4Z" />
   </g> 
        
</svg>
```

### Вариант с 2 секторами + маска + анимация

Каждый раз, разная картинка

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="420" height="420" viewBox="-15 10 420 420" version="1.1">
 <defs>
   <mask id="msk" >
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
   <g id="G1" fill="white" stroke-width="1" stroke="white">
  <path d="1M299.3 119.6A99.6 100.4 90 0 1 198.8 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 1 299.3 318.7 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 399.7 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 299.3 119.6ZM299.3 318.7" />
  <path d="m299.3 318.7a99.6 100.4 1 0 1-97.9-102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 1-101.2 98.8 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 97.9 102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 101.2-98.8z" />
  <path d="1M98.9 316.6A100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 201.4 219.2 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 103 117.5 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 0.5 215 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 98.9 316.6Z" />
  <path d="M101.4 119.4A99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 200.8 220 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 300.6 119.7 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 201.1 19.1 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 101.4 119.4Z" />
   </g> 
   </mask> 
  <animateTransform
       href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="svg1.click"
       dur="8s"
       values="
       0 200 218;
       360 200 218;
       360 200 218;
       0 200 218;
       0 200 218" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       restart="whenNotActive" />   
  </defs>   
  
   <image id="img" mask="url(#msk)"  href=" https://placeimg.com/480/480/nature" width="100%" height="100%"/> 
     
</svg>
```

### Вариант с 4 секторами + анимация

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="420" height="420" viewBox="-15 10 420 420" version="1.1">
 <defs>
   <mask id="msk" >
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
   <g id="G1" fill="white" stroke-width="4" stroke="red">
  <path d="M299.3 119.6A99.6 100.4 90 0 1 198.8 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 1 299.3 318.7 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 399.7 219.2 99.6 100.4 90 0 0 299.3 119.6ZM299.3 318.7" />
  <path d="m299.3 318.7a99.6 100.4 1 0 1-97.9-102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 1-101.2 98.8 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 97.9 102.1 99.6 100.4 1 0 0 101.2-98.8z" />
  <path d="M98.9 316.6A100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 201.4 219.2 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 1 103 117.5 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 0.5 215 100.4 99.6 1.2 0 0 98.9 316.6Z" />
  <path d="M101.4 119.4A99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 200.8 220 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 1 300.6 119.7 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 201.1 19.1 99.6 100.4 0.1 0 0 101.4 119.4Z" />
   </g> 
   </mask> 
  <animateTransform
       href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="svg1.click"
       dur="8s"
       values="
       0 200 218;
       360 200 218;
       360 200 218;
       0 200 218" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       restart="whenNotActive" />   
  </defs>   
  
   <image id="img" mask="url(#msk)"  href="https://placeimg.com/480/480/nature" width="100%" height="100%"/> 

</svg>
```